# Easy way to load local html file in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've been trying to convert a small webapp into an electron application. It's working perfectly, except I need to load a bunch of files (.html) into the main DOM. In the webapp, I just used `$.get`, but how can I do it in electron? I try looking at the DOC but I cannot find an easy way to do that, beside an IPC pipe (and I don't quite get it).

Could anyone point me to the right direction?

**Edit**

I'll clarify here. I have a main process that start a BrowserWindow

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
```

and then, in a `js` file imported via a `<script>` tag, I want to get load and attach some file inside a dialog:

```
$('.dialog').load('pages/hello.html', {})
```

Kind regards

Comment: Can you provide any example (code, actually) of what you're doing in the web app and what you're trying to do in Electron?

Comment: Edited @naeramarth7. I don't know if it's the right approach, maybe I should just migrate the js code inside the main file.

Answer (score 2):

In Electron you can do it with `fs.readFile`

So :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const path = require('path');
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

async function loadHTML(html){
    const render = await readFile(path.join(__dirname, html), 'utf-8');
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const childrenArray = parser.parseFromString(render,'text/html').querySelector('body').childNodes;
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    childrenArray.forEach(item => {
        frag.appendChild(item);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(frag);
};

loadHTML('/path/to/my/index.html');
```

If I don't have a Typo, it should work.
it reads the file as a string so you need to parse this String with the DOMParser.

Comment: Thanks :) The thing is I am trying to do that from the js file imported from the html, which is maybe not the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

On the Electron side you will have this code starting with the `electron` library. With ES6 destructuring you can pull the `app` property off. The `app` object represents the overall running process on your machine.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app } = electron;
```

Then you want to add on an event handler:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
      console.log('app is ready');
});
```

Once you have this running successfully. You have pulled the `app` property which is the underlying process. You have successfully added your event based function using the `app` object.

So you then want to create a new browser window to show content to the user, you pull off another property called `BrowserWindow`, pass it an empty object with your configuration.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

app.on('ready', () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
});
```

You can then load the HTML document by calling the method `loadURL()` passing ES6 template string:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

app.on('ready', () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
```

Comment: This works in dev but not in the prod build for me.

Answer (score 1):

Load like this:

```
`file://${path.join(__dirname,"/../../../../../../src/offline.html")}`
```

Let's try to understand each part:

|  | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| `file` | we will be accessing file protocol, not HTTP directly |
| `__dirname` | comes with node integration in electron, everyone should set it to true |
| `path.join` | else navigating up won't happen actually, it will be simple string concatenation |
| why all those nav up? | maybe it's development dependant, for my case I had to log and find that src directory |

*About that navigating up, I tried on different OS and PC, most of the cases were the same. Except for one exception. Which also had a different config. And I didn't dare to change that, as the config is working.*